# TypeError:'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, streamlit

I have been trying to split the dataset into train and test data for deployment using Streamlit.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold,cross_val_score
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import XGBClassifier


def load_dataset():
    df = pd.read_csv('txn.csv')
    return df

df = load_dataset()


#create X and y, X will be feature set and y is the label - LTV
X = df.drop(['LTVCluster','m1_Revenue'],axis=1)
y = df(['LTVCluster'])
```

But I,m getting this error while executing the file:

**TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable**

```
Traceback:
File "c:\users\anish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)

File "C:\Users\Anish\Desktop\myenv\P52 - Retail Ecommerce\new1.py", line 25, in <module>
    y = df(['LTVCluster'],axis=1)
```

What can be the error??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a extra set of parentheses in your last line, so Python thinks you're calling `df`. To filter by columns in Pandas, you use square brackets, so remove the parentheses.

```py
y = df['LTVCluster']
```

Answer (score -2):

To select a column, remove the () from `df(['LTVCluster'])`:

```py
y = df['LTVCluster']
```